# Running lua file: unexpected symbol near char(226)

Tags: macos, lua

I'm doing a tutorial on learning lua: https://www.lua.org/pil/1.html

I'm trying to open a simple file called hello.lua that I created with Textedit, located in the folder "luaProjects". The file contains the following line:

```
print("Hello World")
```

I get an error however, when I try to run the hello world script like this:

```
luaProjects username$ lua hello.lua
lua: hello.lua:1: unexpected symbol near char(226)
```

I think that lua is installed correctly:

```
User-MacBook-Air:~ username$ lua -v
Lua 5.2.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

And I think that I have set the folder and file up correctly:

```
User-MacBook-Air:luaProjects username$ tree
.
└── hello.lua

0 directories, 1 file
```

**Q:** Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

It could be that your double quotation marks are not ascii, but unicode left/right double quotation marks. Those start with 0xe2, exactly yours 226.

Try some simpler editor, or explicitly save file as ascii.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid saving lua code files as unicode and convert your existing files via:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii YOURFILE
```